# Is it possible to convert my SqlCe 3.5 database to SQL Express 2008 R2 format?

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, sql-server-ce

I have a very simple question, but can't seem to find a strait answer anywhere. I've scoured Google and StackOverflow, but haven't found the answer I'm looking for.

I've created a SqlCe 3.5 database saved as a simple *.sdf file and sits inside my \src directory on a small project. I've just installed Sql Server 2008 Express R2 and want to upgrade this database to the new format so that I can take advantage of Views, Sprocs, and the new Time data type.

Is there any way to import my schema and all of it's data into an empty SQL Server 2008 Express R2 database?

It sounds very elementary, but I simply haven't been able to figure it out. The only thing I can see to do is to script each table and import the data one by one... (?)

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: SqlCe is not the same as SQL Express (2005 or 2008, doesn't matter), the two engines have absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've updated my question... Do you have any tips besides pointing that out?

Comment: Try http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Remus, if you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the 'Accepted Answer'. Thanks so much!! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlCe is not SQL Express. The SDF files created by SqlCe can only be used by SqlCe.

SQL Express is a completely different engine. SQL Express 2005 databases (MDF/LDF) can be opened and upgraded by SQL Server 2008 (Express or non-Express).

Try [exportsqlce.codeplex.com](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com)